# my Linking.getInitalurl() is calling every time when coming to login screen and it is giving url from which it's open but i want the url only once

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"  android:host="qpg.page.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

it's my intent filter for url , and I am using firebase dynamic link url .

```
Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then((url: any) => {
      if (url) {
        console.log('initial Url', url);
        handleLink2(url);
      }
    })
    .catch((err: any) => console.error('An error occurred', err));

  Linking.addEventListener('url', () => {
    console.log('open through link');
    dynamicLinks().onLink(handleLink);
  });
```

what should i do.?

I want to get the url only one time when app loaded using url when app is killed from Linking. getInitalurl , and I am using react-native .
**Not using class component

Answer (score 0):

- Linking.getInitialURL() is asynchronous and returns a promise. This means that the code inside the .then() block will only be executed after the promise is resolved.
- initialUrlHandled state variable to track whether the initial URL has been handled or not. The handleInitialUrl function checks this variable before handling the initial URL. If the initial URL has already been handled, the function does nothing. This ensures that the Linking.getInitialURL() method is only called once, when the app first runs via the URL.
- Dynamic Links : https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage

  ```
  import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
  import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';
  import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

  const App = () => {
   const [initialUrlHandled, setInitialUrlHandled] = 
   useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
    const handleInitialUrl = async () => {
      if (!initialUrlHandled) {
        const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
        if (url) {
          handleLink2(url);
        }
        setInitialUrlHandled(true);
      }
    };

    const handleLink = (url) => {
      handleLink2(url);
    };

    const sub = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleLink);

    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleInitialUrl);

    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleInitialUrl);
      sub();
    };
   }, [initialUrlHandled]);

   const handleLink2 = (url) => {
     // Your URL logic here
   };

   // Your component logic here
  };

  export default App;
  ```
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37641 : Linking.getInitialUrl is null (I know this is a duplicate) #37641
- getInitialLink() returns null if called too soon after launch : https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4548

Comment: I wanted to handle getInitialUrl method of Linking as it's getting call every time when coming to the screen again , eventlistener is only called when app is in foreground so I am handing it in another function as the link is firebase dynamic link, how can I make the  Linking.getInitialLink call only at the time app first run via url

Comment: hey @Mukund Thakur Dev i added some more code to get getInitialUrl method call every time when screen come

Comment: it maybe work as I have used a global variable using redux to store the url at the time of receiving the url so coming back to the screen matches the url if same then doesn't work. btw thanks.